# Simple racing car steering?

Tags: game-mechanics, car, racing

I want to make a simple 2d top-down racing game, something like Mario Kart in 2d, but I am really struggling with the car steering. The only resources I find are complicated and involve a lot of different physics equations. They are all an overkill for my small project.

Do you known how I could implement some simple car steering or do you know some resources? It doesn’t have to be accurate, it should just feel nice to control the car.

I have already tried [Car Physics for Games](http://engineeringdotnet.blogspot.com/2010/04/simple-2d-car-physics-in-games.html?m=1) and some of [this](https://asawicki.info/Mirror/Car%20Physics%20for%20Games/Car%20Physics%20for%20Games.html).

It would be awesome if you could help me!

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? Is there something not working as expected? Here at GameDev users help each other in finding a solution to existing problems, but "How to get started" questions are too broad to be addressed.

Comment: If you don't tell us what you tried or what specific problem you had, then any answer we give you is liable to just repeat advice you already found that didn't work for you. To ensure you can get actionable help quickly, you need to show us more detail about what solutions you've tried.

Comment: How did you try implementing the two approaches you linked, and where specifically did you get stuck?